# How to check past date should not be past from current date in PHP? in this second condition not working

Tags: php

My code is here,I am not able to perfect. when press submit button it check old date correct.. and shows "date must be in future" it correct. and whenever i put future date.. that time not show second alert instead it showing first.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$pdata["card"] = $_POST['smcard'];
$pdata["expiry_date"] = date("Y-m-d" strtotime($_POST['smexdate']));

$dateone =  $pdata["expiry_date"];

$nowdate = new DateTime();

if ($dateone < $nowdate) 
{
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('date must be in future');";
    echo "</script>";
} 
elseif ($dateone > $nowdate) 
{

    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('Okay Good, Your date is in future');";
    echo "</script>";

}
 update_data('smartcard_data', $pdata, 'promotion_id='.$_REQUEST['promotion_id']);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below example to fine date passed or not

```
$dtA = new DateTime('05/14/2010 3:00PM');
$dtB = new DateTime('05/14/2010 4:00PM');

if ( $dtA > $dtB ) {
  echo 'dtA > dtB';
}
else {
  echo 'dtA <= dtB';
}
```

Comment: that second condition elseif not workign
'if(isset($_POST['supdate']))
{
$pdata["expiry_date"] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['smexdate']));
$dateone =  $pdata["expiry_date"];
$nowdate = new DateTime();
if ($dateone < $nowdate) {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('date must be in future');";
    echo "</script>";
} elseif ($dateone > $nowdate) {echo "<script>";
  echo "alert('Okay Good');";
  echo "</script>";


 }
 
 update_data('smartcard_data', $pdata, 'promotion_id='.$_REQUEST['promotion_id']);

 exit;
}'